# Examples of usage of delegates in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

What are some examples of where you would use Delegates in C#/VB.NET and why would you want to use delegates?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687626/the-purpose-of-delegates

Comment: this is not a duplicate question....

Comment: Look at answers. Enough examples where and why to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use delegates all  the time to respond to certain user interaction events. It lets me add functionality for mouseover events, audio started/stopped/playing events, and the like.

Really, delegates are GREAT for when you know you need to respond to a user-initiated event, but you cannot anticipate when that event will occur.