# What are Delegates in c#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [When would you use delegates in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191153/when-would-you-use-delegates-in-c)
>   [The purpose of delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687626/the-purpose-of-delegates)
>   [Delegates, Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567478/delegates-why)
>   [What are the advantages of delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639320/what-are-the-advantages-of-delegates)

What are Delegates in c# and why are they used?

Thanks,

Pradeep

Comment: There are so many similar questions.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687626/the-purpose-of-delegates

Comment: Exact duplicate of about a dozen other questions...  This one closed for the same reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567478/delegates-why-closed

Answer (score 1):

Delegates are essentially method pointers; they are used to call a method from a location unknown at compile-time.  For example, they can be used by events (every time you add an eventhandler, what you're really doing is adding a delegate to your handler to a collection of handlers to be notified when the event is raised.

Answer (score 0):

They are method pointers.

Read more [here](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html).

Answer (score 0):

A delegate is a kind of type that can refer to a method (instance or static). If you are familiar with function pointers in C++, they are conceptually similar.

Since they are a type, an instance of a delegate type can be created and assigned to a method at runtime, this allows you to implement things like callbacks and events.