# What are delegates for?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the advantages of delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639320/what-are-the-advantages-of-delegates)

I have created a sample application. I am really finding it difficult to understand why to use delegates because without delegates we can achieve everything .

```
class Program
{
    public delegate double Integrand(double x);
    static double MyFunc1(double x) { return x + 10; }
    static double MyFunc2(double x) { return x + 20; }

    public static double Gauss3DelMethod(Integrand f)
    {
        double a = f(1);
        return a;
    }

    public static double Gauss3SimpleMethod(double x)
    {
        double a = x;
        return a;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //with delegates
        double res = Gauss3DelMethod(MyFunc1);
        double res1 = Gauss3DelMethod(MyFunc2);

        //without delegates
        double res2 = Gauss3SimpleMethod(MyFunc1(1));
        double res3 = Gauss3SimpleMethod(MyFunc2(1));

        int i = 0;
    }
}
```

So, why should I use delegates?

Comment: "becoz" is misspelling of "becuz", and neither is English.

Comment: @Ian: I think the original title reflects the attitude of the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your particular example, maybe it's *not* important. (It's not clear what it's trying to achieve.)

But suppose you wanted to make the method execute the same `MyFunc1` or `MyFunc2` for several different inputs. For example, suppose you were implementing the [Newton-Raphson method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), to operate over a general function. In that situation, you couldn't call the function *once* and pass that into the method - you want to pass *the actual function* into the method, so that the method can call it with whatever inputs it needs.

A similar example is sorting. For example, using LINQ you can write something like:

```
var sorted = people.OrderBy(x => x.Age).ToList();
```

There we're passing a function to project each source element to the ordering key. We don't have to execute that function ourselves - `OrderBy` will do it for us (lazily).

Of course, all of this can be done with single-method interfaces too - delegates and single-method interfaces have a lot in common. However, delegates have the following benefits over single-method interfaces:

- Delegates are multi-cast - they can be combined/removed, usually for the sake of *events*
- You can execute them asynchronously with BeginInvoke/EndInvoke
- You can build them with anonymous methods and lambda expressions
- You can represent logic as data via expression trees using lambda expresions; these can then be compiled into delegates
- You can build a delegate from any method with the appropriate signature - so for example a single class can have multiple methods "implementing" the same delegate type, whereas you can't implement an interface multiple times in one class
- Likewise delegate implementation methods can be private, whereas interface methods have to be public (or somewhat-public via explicit interface implementation)

All of these could have been addressed differently using single-method interfaces, of course, but delegates are a handy alternative.

In conclusion: delegates are very useful. Just because you've written some trivial code which doesn't particularly require them doesn't mean they're not useful. I would strongly suggest you look into LINQ, event handlers and the TPL, all of which use delegates heavily.

Comment: thanx for ur quick response. can u give me a very basic example?

Comment: @UlhasTuscano: I gave you an example, in words rather than in code - and then one in LINQ, in code. But maybe as an exercise you should try to implement Newton-Raphson yourself. You'll learn more by *doing* it than just by *reading* about it.

Comment: yup i will definitely try it out. thanx

Answer (score 4):

**Delegates are a useful way to pass around functions.**

`Func` and `Action` are also delegates. Without them you couldn't use almost every LINQ method and, beginning from C# 3.0, you can use Lambda Expressions to create them faster.

Imagine for example you have an enumerable of integers:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);
```

By using delegates you can create **higher-order functions** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) that can help you to filter, for example, the numbers above in several ways. `Where` is one of the cases.

You may want to select just odd numbers:

```
var odd = numbers.Where(a => a % 2 == 0);
```

Or even ones:

```
var even = numbers.Where(a => a % 2 != 0);
```

Without them you would have to create a method for each filter (e.g. `WhereOdd` or `WhereEven`)